# MySql WHERE condition based on unique index

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `groupToScore`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `groupToScore` (
  `groupId` int NOT NULL,
  `scoreId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `scoreName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `gToS` (`groupId`,`scoreId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The pair `(groupId, scoreId)` form a unique key `gTos` for this table.

My question is how do I perform `UPDATE` using `gTos` in the `WHERE` clause?
It would look something like, `UPDATE groupToScore SET scoreName = #{scoreName} WHERE gToS is equal to (groupId, scoreId)`.

Comment: Do not use string interpolation for SQL queries, as it makes them vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Even if you know in your current case you know the data is safe, as a matter of principle always use data binding. Always remember the story of little [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE groupToScore SET scoreName = #{scoreName} WHERE groupId = 1 and scoreId = 1;
```

I believe mysql server will choose a proper index for you and you can get the one sql indexing information by put a explain at the top of the sql

```
explain UPDATE groupToScore SET scoreName = #{scoreName} WHERE groupId = 1 and scoreId = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use indices directly. The SQL engine uses the index automatically if it is applicable. Therefore, you simply query for `WHERE groupId = ? AND scoreId = ?`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the key name directly but you can use its expression. Try this:

```
UPDATE groupToScore SET scoreName = #{scoreName} WHERE (`groupId`,`scoreId`) = (groupId, scoreId)
--e.g for a single match
insert groupToScore values(1,3,'dd'),(1,2,'xx');
UPDATE groupToScore SET scoreName = 'aa' WHERE (`groupId`,`scoreId`) = (1, 2);

--e.g for multiple matches
UPDATE groupToScore SET scoreName = 'kk' WHERE (`groupId`,`scoreId`) in (
(1,2),
(1,3)
);
```

Comment: In older versions of MySQL, the "row constructor" (as shown here) fails to use the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
groupId = 1 and scoreId = 1
```

will fail to fully use your

```
UNIQUE KEY `gToS` (`groupId`,`scoreId`)
```

because of a type conflict.

When comparing a varchar column to an integer literal, the column is converted to an integer before performing the test.  Do, instead

```
groupId = 1 and scoreId = "1"
```

It does not matter if you have `groupId = "1"`; the string will be converted to a number and the index can still be used.

The update is simply

```
UPDATE groupToScore SET
    scoreName = #{scoreName}
    WHERE groupId = 123, scoreId = "987"
```

And/or, change the datatype of `scoreId to be something numeric.  (Of course, this assumes its values are really numbers.